# Click-event on a-Tag fires from inner element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I attach a click-Event to an anchor-Tag that wraps around more than a text node, the click event fires from the innermost-node that has been clicked, not the a-node that I attached the event to.

Why? Is there an easy way to access the element to which the firing event has been attached?

```js
document.getElementById("example-link").addEventListener("click", event=>alert("Why does the event fire from the "+event.srcElement.tagName+"-element?"))
```

```html
<a id="example-link" href="#"><p>Click me!</p></a>
```

Comment: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski: Thanks! So `event.currentTarget` points to the element to which the event has been attached. Seriously wondering why this has never been a problem for me. I think I'll have to revise quite a bit of code because I've always used `event.srcElement`in the past. I can see quite a bit of potential for unforeseen behaviour.